# Python - How do I create a test function by using another function?

Tags: python, debugging, testing

I'm having a hard time trying to use another function into a function that tests the function I added with print statements. For example with this function that reverses a string. I want to use print statements in another function that tests the reverse function, but I'm having a hard time understand how I can incorporate the is_reverse function into the testing function without adding parameters into the testing function.

```
def is_reverse( st1, st2 ):
    if len( st1 ) != len( st2 ):
        return False
    i = 0
    j = len( st2 ) - 1
    while j > 0:
        if st1[i] != st2[j]:
            return False
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    return True

def test_is_reverse( ):
    print( "is_reverse( \"hey\", \"yah\" ) == False.\"" )
    print( "is_reverse( \"man\", \"nam\" ) == True.\"" )
```

Comment: So what is wrong with also actually calling the `is_reverse()` function? `print( 'is_reverse( "hey", "yah" ) == False:',  is_reverse( "hey", "yah" ) == False)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can call that, what I meant is that I don't want to do 'test_is_reverse( st1, st2 )', that print is actually an example of the output I want.

Comment: Still not clear here; so why not just use your print functions and test the different scenarios? You can use a loop over over tuples (`for in1, in2, expected in (('hey', 'yah', False), ('man', 'nam', True)):`) if need be to produce parameters, then construct your `print()` and test calls from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to pass the function that you want to use to print the error messages as an argument to the test function.

Something along the lines of:

```
def my_print_func (errmsg):
    print (errmsg)

def test_is_reverse(f ):
    f( "is_reverse( \"hey\", \"yah\" ) == False.\"" )
    f( "is_reverse( \"man\", \"nam\" ) == True.\"" )
```

To test, you do:

```
 test_is_reverse(my_print_func)
```

That said, you should avoid reinventing the wheel and use Python unittest framework, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a function to run your tests and print the results:

```
def test_is_reverse(st1, st2):
    # Define tests here, for example:
    print st1, st2, is_reverse(st1,st2), is_reverse(st2, st1)
    print is_reverse(st1,st1) == is_reverse(sty, st1)
```

Comment: Is there a way of keeping the parameters in 'test_is_reverse( )' empty? And possibly assign 'is_reverse' as a variable. I'm fairly new to this and looking at some examples.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something more specific. Is this an assignment? If so, you should mark it with the "homework" tag.